# Nautilus not working properly , what possibly can be the problem?

Tags: 22.04, nautilus

Whenever I restart my laptop ( Ubuntu 22.04 ) , The file system ( Nautilus ) stops working. It says:-

[Failed to register: Timeout was reached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J30ho.png)

I have a temporary solution as :-

```
killall nautilus 
nautilus -q
```

It works for that time being , but again after some time it's the same problem.

upd: when used `journalctl --user -r` the output is -
*Feb 18 19:50:35 Yash org.freedesktop.FileManager1[21579]: Failed to register: Unable to acquire bus name 'org.gnome.Nautilus'*

Comment: Look in `journalctl --user -r` for errors as to why the previous nautilus instance (it usually tries to connect to it and avoid duplicate processes) is frozen

Comment: Please edit your question and add information if you see a similar error when starting Nautilus via the GNOME Shell.

Comment: It doesn't responds when I try open it from Gnome Shell. Just a loading cursor. @noisefloor

Comment: I have updated the info @DanielT.

Comment: "Unable to acquire bus name" was what I knew was happening and why I asked you. I am looking for logs as to ***why*** the bus name is taken by a frozen nautilus instance